# remove item from stored array in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to remove an item from a stored array in angular 2, with Type Script. I am using a service called **Data Service,** the DataService Code:

```
export class DataService {

    private data: string[] = [];

    addData(msg: string) {
        this.data.push(msg);
    }

    getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    deleteMsg(msg: string) {
        delete [this.data.indexOf(msg)];
    }
}
```

And my component class:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {LogService} from './log.service'
import {DataService} from './data.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'tests',
    template:
            `
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Testing Component</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" placeholder="log meassage" #logo>
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" (click)="logM(logo.value)">log</button>
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-success" (click)="store(logo.value)">store</button>
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger" (click)="send()">send</button>
                <button class="btn btn-md " (click)="show()">Show Storage</button>
                <button (click)="logarray()">log array</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li *ngFor="let item of items" class="list-group-item" #ival>
                        {{item}}
                        <button class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-warning" (click)="deleteItem(ival.value)">Delete
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h3>{{value}}</h3>
            <br>
        </div>
    `
})

export class TestsComponent {

    items: string[] = [];

    constructor(
        private logService: LogService,
        private dataService: DataService) {

    }

    logM(message: string) {
        this.logService.WriteToLog(message);
    }

    store(message: string) {
        this.dataService.addData(message);
    }

    send(message: string) {
    }

    show() {
        this.items = this.dataService.getData();
    }

    deleteItem(message: string) {
        this.dataService.deleteMsg(message);
    }

    logarray() {
        this.logService.WriteToLog(this.items.toString());
    }
}
```

Now, everything is working good except when I try to delete an item. The log shows me that the item is still in the array, and therefore is still shown on the page. How can I remove the item after selecting it with the delete button??

Answer (score 292, accepted):

You can't use `delete` to remove an item from an array. This is only used to remove a property from an object.

You should use [**splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove an element from an array:

```
deleteMsg(msg:string) {
    const index: number = this.data.indexOf(msg);
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.data.splice(index, 1);
    }        
}
```

Comment: **Note:** If you don't check the return of `indexOf()` for `-1`, this will remove the last item from array when `msg` wasn't found!

Comment: flm shokiiiiiiii

Answer (score 172):

I think the Angular 2 way of doing this is the filter method:

```
this.data = this.data.filter(item => item !== data_item);
```

where data_item is the item that should be deleted

Comment: in the template you should use a Pipe to filter your array

Comment: removeArrayItem(objectitem){
 
 this.totalArrayData = this.totalArrayData.filter(item => item.Id !== objectitem.id);
   console.log( this.totalArrayData)
}. It's Working. Thanx

Comment: this worked for me, as for some reason `splice()` was removing everything **except** the value i wanted to remove from the array

Comment: @KaFu -  Can you please show the template part, how are you using pipe

Comment: Anonymous function should have a return for it to work: this.data = this.data.filter(item => return item !== data_item);

Answer (score 41):

Don't use `delete` to remove an item from array and use `splice()` instead.

```
this.data.splice(this.data.indexOf(msg), 1);
```

See a similar question: [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Note, that TypeScript is a superset of ES6 (arrays are the same in both TypeScript and JavaScript) so feel free to look for JavaScript solutions even when working with TypeScript.

Comment: **Note:** If you don't check the return of `indexOf()` for `-1`, this will remove the last item from array when `msg` wasn't found!

Answer (score 18):

```html
<tbody *ngFor="let emp of $emps;let i=index">

<button (click)="deleteEmployee(i)">Delete</button></td>
```

and

```
deleteEmployee(i)
{
  this.$emps.splice(i,1);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use like this:

```
removeDepartment(name: string): void {
    this.departments = this.departments.filter(item => item != name);
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved as follows:

`this.itemArr = this.itemArr.filter( h => h.id !== ID);`

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, splice is not enough especially if your array is involved in a FILTER logic. So, first of all you could check if your element does exist to be absolute sure to remove that exact element:

```
if (array.find(x => x == element)) {
   array.splice(array.findIndex(x => x == element), 1);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a little inefficient since you are doing 2 finds when you can just do 1?

Comment: @rhavelka Depend by the splice angular version: if your splice crash instead of getting null, this code should be safely to avoid unuseful splice..

Comment: Right, I'm not saying your logic is flawed, just that it could be easily optimized. You're doing a `find`, then a `findIndex`, that's two searches when you could do one (like the accepted answer).

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Use `splice()` to remove item from the array its refresh the array index to be consequence.

`delete` will remove the item from the array but its not refresh the array index which means if you want to remove third item from four array items the index of elements will be after delete the element 0,1,4

```
this.data.splice(this.data.indexOf(msg), 1)
```

Comment: how is this different from @Martin's answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the data from array

```
this.data.splice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//declaration 
list: Array<any> = new Array<any>(); 

//remove item from an array 
removeitem() 
{
const index = this.list.findIndex(user => user._id === 2); 
this.list.splice(index, 1); 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

That work for me

```
 this.array.pop(index);

 for example index = 3 

 this.array.pop(3);
```

Comment: pop() removes the last element not the element that you selected