# Remove object from array typescript(Angular 2)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I just try to delete object from array in typescript, in angular 2.4.0, let me show the code, its my html file:

```
button type="submit" (click)="addAnotherLanguague()" >Add non native languague</button>
<li *ngFor="let languague of listOfLanguagues;">
     <div class="form-item form-item--text">
           <label class="label invisible">Years studied</label>
           <input type="number" min="0" [(ngModel)]="languague.yearsStudied" name="years"  placeholder="Years studied"/>
     </div>
<button type="submit" (click)="removeLanguague(languague)" >Remove</button> // here you can see use of method
</li>
```

And there is component.ts

```
(...)
this.listOfLanguagues = new Array <LanguagueInformationData>();
    }
addAnotherLanguague(){
        this.listOfLanguagues.push(new LanguagueInformationData);
    }
    removeLanguague(languague){
        this.listOfLanguagues.slice(this.listOfLanguagues.indexOf(languague), 1);
    }
(...)
```

Adding works well, but I tried everything to remove and still dont know how to transfer that languague's reference, I dont want to use .pop, because I want to remove exactly this languague below which is button.
Can you help me?

[edit]
I got problem again with this code, because every time I try to add new languague(push) it clears my data on classes existing in array, do you know what can cause it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove item from stored array in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462369/remove-item-from-stored-array-in-angular-2)

Comment: I edited a little bit my question, cause of new issue

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`<li *ngFor="let languague of listOfLanguagues; let i = index">`

`<button type="submit" (click)="removeLanguague(languague, i)" >Remove</button>`

```
removeLanguague(languague, index){
    this.listOfLanguagues.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: why pass the language parameter if not using it?

Comment: @Ricardo Gellman IMO language object will require when you make a service call to delete language from database as well.

Answer (score 13):

You have to use `splice` and not `slice`

```
this.listOfLanguagues.splice(this.listOfLanguagues.indexOf(languague), 1);
```

`slice` returns a section of an array, and `splice` removes elements from an array and, if necessary, inserts new elements in their place, returning the deleted elements