# I would like to add a remove button in my Angular App

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an Angular App, I would like to add a remove button for a div element, I currently have an add button, which is as follows:

ts file.

```
uploads = [];

 addUp() {
    this.uploads.push(this.uploads.length);
  }
```

I have tried

```
removeUp() {
        this.uploads.remove(this.uploads.length);
      }
```

This code is linked to this button as follows:

```
<button class="btn" (click)="addUp()">Add</button>
```

HTML

```
    <div class="col" *ngFor="let upload of uploads">
       <h2>Upload</h2>
    </div>
```

How would I do the remove version?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: First maybe read about Javascript arrays?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

Comment: @rob: Please give some feedback if some answer worked or if you found another solution. Thanks for your update!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the function `remove` to remove an item from an array.

#### *splice* to remove an object from an array

To remove an element from an array you should use [**splice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
removeUpload(uploadItem) {
    // get index/position of uploadItem within array
    const index: number = this.uploads.indexOf(uploadItem);

    // if index returned is negative it means element not found in array
    // else: (positive) index can be used 
    // e.g. to remove the single element at this position
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.uploads.splice( index, 1 );
    }
}
```

This removes from index-position exactly one single element (thus second argument is `1` here).

Of course you to have add the argument `upload` as argument to button's click-event, so that the function knows which element of the array it has to remove:

```
<button class="btn" (click)="removeUpload( upload )" title="remove this">x</button>
```

See [demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asncms).

#### Shortcuts

If you want to remove the **first** element of the array, use array.[shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).
If you want to remove the **last** element of the array, use array.[pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
Both functions return the removed element.

#### What to add/remove from the array?

I am not sure why you add/remove (`push` respective `splice`) the array's length to the `uploads` array. Does the array store the current size of itself or rather upload-item-objects ?

#### See also

[A: remove item from stored array in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40462431/5730279)

Comment: The uploads will be an input where you upload files to, Its just a <h2> tag for now but the concept is the same its adding and removing the element.

Comment: That remove button didn't work - no errors in console

Comment: @rob Sorry, did fix my code `splice(uploadItem,1)` must be `splice(index, 1)` as you already recognized. And added the button-HTML. Find **complete demo** linked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are trying to achieve the the same button implementation but for the remove method.

Use : `<button class="btn" (click)="removeUp()">Remove</button>`

And also change the removeUp method to use `splice` instead of `remove`:

```
removeUp() {

   this.uploads.splice(this.uploads.length, 1)

}
```

Look at a similar question being answered here [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Alexandros but that code in the TS file does not work for removing the element

Comment: Ok so your problem is the removeUp method. What are you trying to remove? The last element of the list uploads?

Comment: Check the new edited answer. The extra html you edited using the `ngFor` is correct but i see that you are not using that `upload` object of the list. You are just showing Element as text of the h2. Shouldn't you use it?

Comment: Dear @rob please always tell us WHAT and HOW something does not work (i.e. include: console-output, error-message, stacktrace, etc.). Then we can analyze faster and directly solve it.

Comment: Ok hc_dev will do next time

Comment: So pressing the remove button does not remove the last element? If there was a reproduction or a github repo we could look into it in more depth. Consider making - sharing one. You could use codepen or something similar having angular bundled.

Comment: @AlexandrosMarkovits Did you test your code ;-) Using the **length** as _start/index_-argument to `splice` will **remove nothing**. I also thought it would roll-over. But only **start-index > length** will be 0 effectively, and **negative start/index** will be count from last-element.

Comment: No, I didn't think of anything like this could happen. Though i must say that pushing or splicing the length of the array in the array as an element is pretty weird. Good job on finding the solution.